# Service sometimes working, sometimes not working

Tags: centos, connection, telnet

I want to connect Centos B's 33060 port from Centos A.

I can ping Server B.

```
[root@serverb ~]# ping 10.42.40.182
PING 10.42.40.182 (10.42.40.182) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.42.40.182: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=1.51 ms
64 bytes from 10.42.40.182: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=1.51 ms
64 bytes from 10.42.40.182: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=1.50 ms
64 bytes from 10.42.40.182: icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=1.51 ms
64 bytes from 10.42.40.182: icmp_seq=5 ttl=56 time=1.54 ms
64 bytes from 10.42.40.182: icmp_seq=6 ttl=56 time=1.58 ms
```

But when I try to telnet 33060. Sometimes it is working. Most of the time not working. I'll be waiting for the following status.

[root@db2019 ~]# telnet 10.42.40.182 33060
Trying 10.42.40.182...

I tried another Centos to connect to B's 33060. It is always working.

Please advise what's the possible reasons. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think, you are pinging serverb from inside:

> [root@serverb ~]# ping 10.42.40.182

Two be able to connect two hosts (same network):

- each should be in the same subnetwork
- firewall should be disabled or at least port 33060 tcp/udp should be open on serverB for incoming traffic and for serverA for outgoing traffic

Possible solutions:

Check if app is responding from serverA and serverB

```
$ nc -zv 10.42.40.182 33060
```

Check if app on serverB is bound to physical interface 10.42.40.182 not only localhost or loopback interface (127.0.0.1)

```
$ netstat -tulpn | grep 33060
```

Check firewall rules (serverA and serverB)

```
$ iptables -L
```